# CTA Button - Button too short to contain verbs

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, buttons, verb

In one of my iOS mobile apps I’m showing a screen with 2 options:

- The first option, on the left side, is an outlined button that performs a free action.
- The second option, on the right, is a solid butto) that performs an action for which payment is required.

I would like the user to choose the paid option.

Here’s a screenshot of the setup:

[image]

I've seen in many places that a CTA button should start with a verb but as you can see, adding **Export** to the beginning of each button, is not an option, due to lack of space.

However, I don't think placing them one-above-the-other is a good idea, because it will reduce the compression between than, and I need the users to eventually tap the 'Full HD' button.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You could also test with two radio buttons, with one big button "Start" below it.

Comment: Is the left option truly Low Quality, or Standard? If Standard, you could use "Get SD" and "Get HD". "Low Quality" and "Full" are pretty wordy descriptors that could probably be eliminated or reduced.

Comment: @Leatherwing It's standard basically. The real challenge is the microcopy. As for not many know what SD is, and it will create frustration. IMO. I wish it was easier to come up with those short titles

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Thank you for your suggestion :) I'm going to both-at-same-line UI for now (works good)

Comment: Note that the text should say "In what quality *would you like* to export" (or "...*do you want* to export"). The text currently in the screenshot is not good English.

Comment: @Leatherwing "Full HD" is the standard 'market' name for 1080p HD.  If that is what is output, then that is what it should say.  On the other hand, many new mobile devices can support 4k these days, so if that is supported, another term should be used, as "Full HD" would be misleading.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Starting CTA with a verb is a recommended way to go but in no way set in stone. Otherwise you would have strange situations like the one you're dealing with now, just because of some 'rule'.

Something else you could try is to put the verb in the label text above (picture one) or change the text to the user's perspective (picture two).

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! I'm amazed I haven't thought about this my self. Btw,Is it a must to align-left the label above or can I keep it centered same as my picture? (In sake of symmetric)

Comment: There's a lot of talk about label placement. Personally, I think left top aligned works best. Here's a link with research: http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2006/07/label-placement-in-forms.php

Comment: Thanks, I'm coming from the development world, so every piece of knowledge from the product perspective is priceless. One last question, any reason why you excluded "Export" (the verb) from the title in the second option? So it'll be something like: "I want to export my video in..."?, Or nothing specific?

Comment: Maybe it was a length consideration?

Comment: To make it easier for less technical users. The term 'export' is something we all know, but maybe your users don't. In the second picture I tried to label it like a user's thought. "I want my video in Full HD". The same theory can be applied to "full hd" by the way. Maybe change it to low and high quality?

Comment: I thought about it for hours, "Full HD" vs "High Quality". I came to conclusion that even tho "Low Quality" vs "High Quality" is far making more sense. "Full HD" is a "stronger" word in terms of pure quality. And placing "High Quality" vs "Full HD", "Full HD" takes in terms of better connotation. Am I BS'ing here or am I making sense?

Comment: It makes sense. The option you want your users to select sounds stronger now. Make sure to test this with your (potential) users.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated. Your answers always giving me confident too keep forward!

Comment: @RoiMulia Another way would be going with just "SD" and "HD" for the buttons, though that may still have more connotations for people who are used to specific resolutions for Standard Definition versus High Definition.

Comment: @JAB As far as I know, "SD" Is not widely known (at least the shortcut). And I'm afraid it will cause confusion instead of comparison

Comment: I'm not convinced this is good UX. It probably depends on the context of your app, how much work the user had committed to already for example. But I would try to press the HD button, get asked to signup/upgrade/pay and then promptly leave.

It might be good for conversion rate, though.

Comment: @Ben currently the conversion rate are doing well. There is a lot of gaps but eventually I tried presenting the top two I thoughts would look the best compared to each other. There are tons of stuff I could actually try, but due to time limit I can't test everything. So i'm just going hard with my intuitiveness

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the feeling of an arrow facing right, with thick fill, like from the Arial Black font set, could suffice for a verb CTA